# correct source code for developing and loading kernel

Tags: source-code, ubuntu-drivers

I want to develop char drivers on my system:

```
#lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Kernel info:

3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:23:47 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

My question is:

Do I need to download the same version of kernel for driver development and loading?
If so, how do I download the same version using command line?

I tried :

```
 # apt-get source linux-source-3.8.0-38-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for linux-source-3.8.0-38-generic
```

but failed!!

Answer (score 0):

To install the kernel source, try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

to obtain the source for the currently running kernel you can alos use the command:

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

To obtaining the kernel sources for an Ubuntu release using git:

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-`<release>`.git
```

Replace `<release>` with interesting one, ie

- raring (13.04) kernel source 3-8.0
- saucing (13.10) kernel source 3-11.0

You can download the  linux source package directly from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-source).

Refer to [ubuntu pages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode) for more help.

Comment: This tries to download a version which is different from what I am running. ...Skipping already downloaded file 'linux-meta_3.2.0.60.71.dsc'
(as I once downloaded it )

Comment: I edited my answer.  It is strange that the command installs a different version of the source from that of the kernel. try updating first with apt-get update.

Comment: I used this:git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git   it gives a folder ubuntu-precise . will this work?

Comment: @user2799508 just finished downloading you will have the kernel source code of ubuntu precise (version 3.2.0)